# Modifying System Theme of AOSP ( Android-Source ) for Automotive

Tags: android, android-source, android-theme, automotive, android-automotive

I need to customize the System Theme of Android Automotive, when i check the developer guide i could find that AOSP supports that and as per the [developer site](https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/hmi#system_theme) it is mentioned like

> "OEM's are expected to have a parallel overlay structure to the
>   car_product directory in their vendor directory that further extends
>   the car_product overlay."

I need to create an overlay structure like the car_product in the vendor directory , Could anybody guide me to create the same . I have tried some methods mentioned in the [sites](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-theme-android-with-the-runtime-resource-overlay-framework--cms-29708) , but these are not the same as mentioned in the developer site.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are static resource overlay (different than Runtime Resource Overlays).
Take a look at the [system UI section](https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/hmi/system_ui) of the android automotive documentation. It explains more how to use the resource overlay.

[This Stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9473995/1245894) is also giving some details.